# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ConcejalesFormulario::data()

Tags: php, undefined

Quisiera saber que podría ser, sucede que tengo quizá unos 3 o 4 formularios hechos de la misma manera, con el método "data" declarado siempre de la misma forma `$data = $this->data();` pero justo en este formulario no me funciona y me tira error 500 "está página no funciona".

Si alguien puede ayudarme declarando el método o solucionando este error, agradeceré en gran manera.

Ya busqué por todos los post existentes sobre este error y ninguno me deja en claro que es lo que debo hacer.

Detallo el error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ConcejalesFormulario::data() in /var/www/html/sam/sys/application/controllers/concejalesFormulario.php:21\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/cisystem/214/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(359): ConcejalesFormulario->index()\n#1 /var/www/html/sam/sys/index.php(202): require_once('/var/www/html/c...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/sam/sys/application/controllers/concejalesFormulario.php on line 21

Aquí está mi controlador:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
exit('No direct script access allowed');
}

class ConcejalesFormulario extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('url'));
    $this->load->model('concejales', TRUE);
    $this->load->library(array('session'));
    $this->load->library(array('Bouncer', 'Manager', 'Validate'));
    $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0", "Pragma: no-cache");
    $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
}

function index($success = NULL) {
    $this->bouncer->allower();
    $data = $this->data();  //se supone que el error es aquí//
    $views = array(
        array('view' => 'templates/bannerProfile', 'data' => $data),
        array('view' => 'modulos/concejales/header', 'data' => $data),
        array('view' => 'modulos/concejales/concejalesRegistrados', 'data' => $data),
        array('view' => 'modulos/concejales/formularioConcejales', 'data' => $data),
    );
    if ($success == 'success') {
        array_unshift($views, array('view' => 'popup/alerta', 'data' => $this->alert(TRUE)));
    }
    $this->manager->layout($views);
}

public function registrarConcejales() {
    $sasession = $this->session->userdata('sasession');
    $id_municipio = $sasession['id_municipio'];
    $data = $this->input->post();

    if ($this->validarRegistro($data)) {
        $dataConcejales = array('nombrecomp' => $data['nombrecomp'], 'partidopol' => $data['partidopol'], 'emailconc' => $data['emailconc'], 'telefonoconc' => $data['telefonoconc']);
        if ($this->concejales->registrar($data)) {
            echo 'ok';
        } else {
            $this->systemError();
        }
    } else {
        $alertdata = $this->alert(FALSE, 'Uno o varios valores indicados no son v&aacute;lidos.<br/>No se guardaron los cambios. Intentalo nuevamente.');
        $this->load->view('popup/alerta', $alertdata);
    }
}

private function validarRegistro($data) {
    if (!($this->validate->isAlpha($data['nombrecomp']) and $data['partidopol'] !='' and $data['emailconc'] != '' and $data['telefonoconc'] != NULL)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
    }

 }
```

Aquí mi modelo:

```
    <?php

Class Concejales extends CI_Model {

function __construct() {
    $this->load->library(array('snippets'));
    $this->load->model('registro', '', TRUE);
}

function registrar($id_municipio, $data) {
    $portal_web_db = $this->load->database('dnc_sys', TRUE);

    $portal_web_db->where('id_municipio', $id_municipio);
    $portal_web_db->update('concejales', $data);

    $dataRegistro['id_municipio'] = $id_municipio;
    $dataRegistro['id_accion'] = 5;
    $dataRegistro['tabla'] = 'concejales';
    $dataRegistro['descripcion'] = "Actualización del número de empleados";
    $this->registro->registrar($dataRegistro);

    return $portal_web_db->affected_rows() ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function comprobacion($id_municipio) {
    $dnc_sys_db = $this->load->database('dnc_sys', TRUE);

    $dnc_sys_db->select('nombrecomp, partidopol, emailconc, telefonoconc');
    $dnc_sys_db->from('concejales');
    $dnc_sys_db->where('id_municipio', $id_municipio);
    $dnc_sys_db->limit(1);
    $query = $dnc_sys_db->get();
    //$numero = FALSE;
    return $query->num_rows() >= 1 ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
}
```

---

Hola en respuesta a sus comentarios, (aclaro que formule yo la pregunta, y no me dejó apropiarme de ella a la hora de registrarme, por eso público esta respuesta, también aclaro que estoy utilizando CodeIgniter 1.0) no encontré la definición del método en CI_controller si no que en el Manager, aquí se los presento:

```
class Manager {

private $ci;

function __construct() {
    $this->ci = & get_instance();
    $this->ci->load->model('info_usuarios', '', TRUE);
    $this->ci->load->model('municipios', '', TRUE);
    $this->ci->load->model('participantes', '', TRUE);
    $this->ci->load->model('solicitantes', '', TRUE);
    $this->ci->load->model('concejales', '', TRUE);
    $this->ci->load->model('planes_capacitacion', '', TRUE);
    $this->ci->load->library(array('form_validation'));
    $this->ci->load->library(array('Bouncer', 'FormatTime', 'Manager', 'TextHandle', 'FilesHandle'));
}

function layout($views) {
    $this->ci->bouncer->allower();
    $data = $this->data();
    $mdata = array(
        'views' => $views,
        'data' => $data
    );
    $this->ci->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->ci->load->view('templates/navbar');
    $this->ci->load->view('templates/layout', $mdata);
    $this->ci->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}

function data() {
    $sasession = $this->ci->session->userdata('sasession');
    $id_usuario = $sasession['id_municipio'];
    $info_usuario = $this->ci->info_usuarios->info($id_usuario);
    $estadoMunicipio = $this->ci->municipios->comprobacion($id_usuario);
    $estadoParticipantes = $this->ci->participantes->comprobacion($id_usuario);
    $estadoPlanes = $this->ci->planes_capacitacion->comprobacion($id_usuario);
    $n_empleados_capacitados = count($this->ci->solicitantes->info('id_solicitante', array('id_municipio' => $sasession['id_municipio'])));

    $data = array(
        'title' => ucfirst('SAM'),
        'info_usuario' => $info_usuario[0],
        'estadoMunicipio' => $estadoMunicipio,
        'estadoParticipantes' => $estadoParticipantes,
        'estadoPlanes' => $estadoPlanes,
        'estado' => (($estadoMunicipio ? 1 : 0) * .33 + ($estadoPlanes ? 1 : 0) * .34 + ($estadoParticipantes ? 1 : 0) * .33) * 100,
        'n_empleados_capacitados' => $n_empleados_capacitados
    );

    $data['format_time'] = & $this->ci->formattime;
    $data['text'] = & $this->ci->texthandle;
    return $data;
   }
}
```

Comment: pero donde estas definiendo  la funcion data??

Comment: Hola Brown. Creo que pueden darse dos situaciones. Partiendo del punto donde te indica el error `ConcejalesFormulario::data()` no existe, bien porque el método no existe realmente en la clase o porque no se encuentra esta clase y este método claro (la clase no está cargada o tiene un namespace que no permite encontrarla). Siempre desde el punto que te lanza el error: "/var/www/html/sam/sys/application/controllers/concejalesFormulario.php", línea 21

Comment: Dos cosas: el controlador no tiene definido el método data, por lo que o se te ha olvidado o está en el CI_controller. Puedes poner el código del ci_controller?